# Why is MySQL date between throwing an error?

Tags: mysql, date, between

Can this query be possible in MySQL, I have tried different versions of MySQL but did not work, same query works in postgresSQL.

```
select * 
  from BetweenDateDemo 
 where StartDate between >= '2014-8-12' and curdate();
```

Comment: I don't believe that this query works in postgres. Or any other DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

the right syntax is:

```
select * from BetweenDateDemo where StartDate between '2014-8-12' and curdate();
```

See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html) for further reference.

You are currently mixing Between with the explicit notation > <